# Removing an item from a listbox in C#

Tags: c#, listbox, indexoutofrangeexception

Hello I'm trying to click a button to remove and item but I keep getting an

> 'IndexOutOfRange' Exception.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clientNum = clientList.Items.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < clientNum; i++)
    {
        nameSeletion[i] = clientList.Items[i].ToString();
    }

    if (dateSeletion[clientList.SelectedIndex] != null)
    {
        dateCalender.SelectionStart = todayDate[clientList.SelectedIndex];
        Check();
    }
    else
    {
        nameLbl.Text = nameSeletion[clientList.SelectedIndex];
        dateText.Text = "";
    }
}
```

The `if (dateSeletion[clientList.SelectedIndex] != null)` is where I'm having the error.

The button code is

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clientList.Items.Remove(clientList.Items[clientList.SelectedIndex]);
}
```

the dateSelection is defined in the save button and Initialization

```
private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //save the list array for names
        for (int i = 0; i < clientNum; i++)
        {
            nameSeletion[i] = clientList.Items[i].ToString();
        }

        dateSeletion[clientList.SelectedIndex] = dateCalender.SelectionStart.Date.ToShortDateString() +
            " " + clientTime.Value.ToShortTimeString();
        todayDate[clientList.SelectedIndex] = dateCalender.SelectionStart;
        dateCalender.BoldedDates = todayDate;
        Check();

    }

public ClientForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        clientNum = clientList.Items.Count;
        todayDate = new DateTime[clientNum];
        dateSeletion = new string[clientNum];
        nameSeletion = new string[clientNum];
        clientTime.CustomFormat = "hh:mm tt";

        //initialize the list array for names
        for (int i = 0; i < clientNum; i++)
        {
            nameSeletion[i] = clientList.Items[i].ToString();
        }

    }
```

Comment: And what is `dateSeletion` where it is defined? and populated?

Comment: added where the dataSelection is defined

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
clientList.RemoveAt(clientList.SelectedIndex);
```

Comment: I still get the same error. I think it has something to do with the dateSelection, I'm just not sure what.